# get column names after join in teradata

Tags: python, sql, teradata, pyodbc

I am  using  python API to connect with tera data, when I use select * query on any pre-existing table I can get column info by Help Table Query. But Now I am using joins and other queries which includes multiple tables. i am receiving data correct but I do not know how to access column names of respective fields to replicate those generated data in other format using API. Please help Me.

Answer (score 1):

Column information is returned in [cursor.description](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#description).

For a list of column names:

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
```

Note that I haven't specifically tested this with Teradata, but it works for other DBMSs.